# Почему нельзя изменять код, созданный Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Мне часто говорили, что нельзя изменять код, созданный Qt Designer, будет не работать. 
Я достаточно часто под себя изменяю код, но при этом все идеально работает, без каких-либо ошибок.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще менять можно (код-то работать будет), но **настоятельно** не рекомендуется. И вот почему.

Представим ситуацию: вы создали приложение, изменили код, созданный через `QtDesigner`. А потом вам/заказчику захотелось изменений в интерфейсе будь то новые возможности ПО или просто дизайн. Вы меняете старый интерфейс на новый в `QtDesigner` и вам теперь придется снова **менять новый сгенерированный файл**. Это займет много времени и, скорее всего, приведет к ошибкам в коде.

А теперь представим то же приложение, но вы не меняли файл, а импортировали его и написали "обертку". Тогда вам просто нужно:

1. при чисто дизайновом (косметическом) изменение приложения -
   изменить дизайн в QtDesigner
2. при добавлении нового функционала: дописать новый функционал в обертку, изменить интерфейс в QtDesigner.

Как видите, действий во втором случае гораздо меньше, плюс используется принцип *повторного использования*, что дает выгоду и во времени и в качестве разработки.

Answer (score 3):

Как говорится в предупреждении в заголовке всех сгенерированных `pyuic` файлов,
вам не следует редактировать их, если вы действительно не знаете, что делаете.
И если вы знаете, что делаете, вы не будете их редактировать.
**`Это вежливый способ сказать: вы никогда не должны редактировать эти файлы.`**

То, что генерирует утилита `pyuic`, всегда должно использоваться
как импортированный модуль, и его никогда нельзя редактировать
или использовать в качестве отправной точки для вашей программы.
Рассматривайте его как файл ресурсов (как изображение или данные json);
см. [**документацию**](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) об этом.

Для этого есть несколько причин, наиболее важная из которых заключается в том,
что всякий раз, когда вы редактируете файл пользовательского интерфейса,
созданный в Designer,
вам придется объединять свой код с кодом из нового сгенерированного файла py,
что, вероятно, приведет к неожиданному результату или,
в большинстве случаев головная боль возникает из-за расхождений между
написанным вами логическим кодом и модификациями,
которые вы внесли в графический интерфейс.