# PyQT5 + Pandas, открытие файла Excel

Tags: python, excel, pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Необходимо подгружать файл *Excel* через `QFileDialog` и дальше он должен попадать в *pandas* и создаваться дата фрейм для дальнейших манипуляций.

Кнопка создана, диалоговое окно открывается, но при выборе файла программа завершается с ошибкой:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Не совсем понятно почему? 
Сам по себе `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` ничего не открывает, а передает кортеж с путем для файла и типом файла, я забираю из него **`0`** индекс (с путем) и показываю его *pandas*. 
Как я вижу, что я сделал.

Сам код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.UpLoad_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setFont(font)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.UpLoad_btn.setObjectName("UpLoad_btn")
        self.cr_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.cr_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 0, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.cr_btn.setFont(font)
        self.cr_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.cr_btn.setObjectName("cr_btn")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 800, 511))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_functions()


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.UpLoad_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузка"))
        self.cr_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Покажи"))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.UpLoad_btn.clicked.connect(self.upload_xlsx)

    def upload_xlsx(self):
        fnameTuple = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.UpLoad_btn, 'Open Excel File ', "D:/Ucheba", "Excel File (*.xlsx)")
        fname = fnameTuple[0]
        df = pd.read_excel(fname)
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Напишите `import pandas as pd` вместо `import pandas` и нужно добавить проверку на то что `fnameTuple` != `('','')` (Если нажать отмена)

Comment: Да, я забыл дать короткое обращение к pandas и к нему обращался. as pd все решил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получать реальную ошибку - всегда запускайте ваше приложение 
в консоли/терминале/CMD.

[**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА.**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492882/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-qt-designer/1492904#1492904) 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Файлы ***.xlsx** надо показывать в таблице `QTableWidget()` или
`QTableView()`, 
а не в `QTextBrowser()`.

Загрузить и показать в `QTableWidget()` можно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd                                                     # <---- 


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.UpLoad_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setFont(font)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.UpLoad_btn.setObjectName("UpLoad_btn")
        
        '''
# ???
        self.cr_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.cr_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 0, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.cr_btn.setFont(font)
        self.cr_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.cr_btn.setObjectName("cr_btn")
# ???
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 800, 511))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        '''
# !!! +++
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()                          # !!! +++
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

#-        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.UpLoad_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузка"))
#        self.cr_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Покажи"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                   # <---- 
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)                                                # <---- 
        
#-    def add_functions(self):
        self.UpLoad_btn.clicked.connect(self.upload_xlsx) 
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)   
        layout.addWidget(self.UpLoad_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def upload_xlsx(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Open Excel File ', 
            "", 
            "Excel File (*.xlsx)"
        )
#-        fname = fnameTuple[0]
        
        if fname:
            df = pd.read_excel(fname)
            #print(df)
            self.loadExcelData(df)
            
    def loadExcelData(self, df):
        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)
        
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                                 # <---- 
    w.show()                                                         # <---- 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только не совсем понятно почему мы не можем подключится к тем кнопкам и виджетам, что нам сделал _Qt Designer_ , а мы должны создать отдельный класс и в нем завести кнопки и виджеты?  Как Вы сделали в Вашем примере.

Comment: @LivsiMD  я добавил в свой ответ ссылку почему это делать не надо 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492882/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-qt-designer/1492904#1492904

Comment: попытался Ваш код переделать под свои ну;ы, но столкнулся со сложностью. После прохождение _.str.contains_  у меня должен формироваться новый датафрейм, и уже его я хотел вывести так же как и на Вашем примере. Но это не работает. Не совсем понимаю почему. Ошибка    <code>FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
  df2.fillna('', inplace=True)     <code>

Comment: @LivsiMD если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 0):

@S. Nick

Ошибка

> FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and
> will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '' has dtype
> incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible
> dtype first.   df2.fillna('', inplace=True)

Я понимаю, что ему не нравится тип данных. Но я и не менял, только прошелся отобрав нужные мне строки.

То что я пытался изменить.

```
def upload_xlsx(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open Excel File ',
            "",
            "Excel File (*.xlsx)"
        )
        # -        fname = fnameTuple[0]

        if fname:
            df = pd.read_excel(fname)
            tags = [r'\bн/о', r'\bакту', r'\bно3', r'\bМОУ']
            df2 = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains('|'.join(tags))]
            self.loadExcelData(df2)

    def loadExcelData(self, df2):
        df2.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df2.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df2.shape[1])
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df2.columns)

        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem
```

)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).